# Using tensorflow missing libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying to use the deeplearning tool deeplabcut. It used to run on my machine, but now when I try to train a dataset I get the error:

NOT_FOUND: Key efficientnet/efficientnet-b6/blocks_0/conv2d/kernel not found in checkpoint

I have tried installing different versions of tensorflow, checked that my tensorflow, driver,nvdia, and conda environments were all compatible.
I even redid the whole installation on a different machine/GPU, with both python 3.9 and 3.8. The error messages are always the same, indicating that there are some missing libraries in the checkpoint.

Comment: When running this line to check installation and that it is working with the GPU 
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

I get error:
W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.

Comment: I am now getting the error "tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:313] kernel version 470.86.0 does not match DSO version 545.23.6 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration
Num GPUs Available:  0"

When testing for GPU compatibility. Do I need to update my NVDIA or my cuda? To which version? Nvdia websites are not being very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your doing something wrong. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/61468
There it says this is not right and maybe the same.

But when not take a look at.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc

Your error suggested line 38 there.
There it says the function is about `GOOGLE_CUDA && GOOGLE_TENSORRT`.

```
bool IsGoogleTensorRTEnabled() {
#if GOOGLE_CUDA && GOOGLE_TENSORRT
#if TF_USE_TENSORRT_STATIC
  LOG(INFO) << "TensorRT libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check";
  return true;
#else   // TF_USE_TENSORRT_STATIC
  auto handle_or = se::internal::DsoLoader::TryDlopenTensorRTLibraries();
  if (!handle_or.ok()) {
    LOG_WARNING_WITH_PREFIX << "Could not find TensorRT";
  }
  return handle_or.ok();
#endif  // TF_USE_TENSORRT_STATIC
#else   // GOOGLE_CUDA && GOOGLE_TENSORRT
  return false;
#endif  // GOOGLE_CUDA && GOOGLE_TENSORRT
}
```

Hope this is specific enough!